# cannot read property 'addeventlistener' of null using Google Place Autocomplete API

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have a problem trying to implement Google Place Autocomplete API.  I have been working in asp.net C# project.  When I am typing a place name in the textbox, it shows a place option.  However, when I am selecting the option it does not show the location on the map the first time, but when I select it a second time, it does show on the map.

I debugged the JavaScript, and it shows an error as `cannot read property 'addeventlistener' of null`.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
        function Initialize() {

        var mapOptions = {

            center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.669156500000000000, 77.453757799999950000),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

        };
        var input = document.getElementById('txtPickUpPoints');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('GMap1'), mapOptions);


        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {

            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(17);
            }
        });
        //document.getElementById("lbl_lati").innerHTML = "good going";
        //document.getElementById("lbl_longi").innerHTML =      document.getElementById('TextBox1').value = GMap1.get.lng();
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', Initialize);



  I am using 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?    sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: Possibly `document.getElementById('GMap1')` is returning *null* because it can't find an element with id *GMap1*.

Comment: i have added GMap1 in div and it recoginize for second time selection of place

Comment: Ok. The error indicates that *null* is where an element is expected, and the usual suspect is *getElementById*. Perhaps it's elsewhere.